# Can I control an iPad with an Apple TV remote?

Tags: ipad, video, appletv, remote-control, tv.app

Normally I watch TV and Movies using an Apple TV. I love being able to easily Pause and Skip Backward/Forward using the Apple TV's Siri Remote.

But in other places in the house I might watch on an iPad. Or even sometimes on an iPhone.

When I'm watching, I often prop the iPad up on a table or otherwise out of reach. So it's inconvenient to touch the screen. In the worst case, tapping the screen might tip over the iPad. I really just want to use a remote.

#### Is it possible to control an an iPad with an Apple TV Siri Remote via Bluetooth?

---

<sup>Note: I'm *not* asking about controlling an Apple TV with the iOS "Remote" app. I want the the reverse.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to use the remote which comes with an Apple TV to control the iPad, but you *can* connect an Apple or third-party bluetooth keyboard to control your iPad.

Quoth Apple:

> #### Apple Wireless Keyboard and Magic Keyboard compatibility with iOS devices
>
> Apple Wireless Keyboard, Magic Keyboard, and many Bluetooth keyboards that use the Apple keyboard layout work with these iOS devices.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202041
>
> Note: In addition to Apple keyboards, many third-party Bluetooth keyboards that use the Apple keyboard layout work with iOS devices. Check with the keyboard manufacturer for additional information.

After connecting a Bluetooth keyboard, [Mac-like keyboard shortcuts](https://www.cultofmac.com/552183/ipad-video-keyboard-commands/) will work to control video playback on the iPad. Spacebar to play/pause, arrow keys to skip forward and backward and to control the volume.